# Unable to create resources using Terraform with contributors's access to specific RG in Azure

Tags: azure, terraform

In Azure portal, I have only read access at the subscription and tenant level. But I have full contributor access to a specific Resource Group. The script passes in the planning phase but keeps failing no matter how many different types of scripts I use during applying it.

Firstly, I tried the code below:
Sample 1:

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        azurerm = {
            source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
            version = "=3.0.0"
        }
    }
}
provider "azurerm" {  
    skip_provider_registration = true
    features {}
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mytststorageacc" {
    name                     = "mytststorageacc"
    resource_group_name      = "my_RG"
    location                 = "centralindia"
    account_tier             = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
```

Error:

```
Creating Azure Storage Account "mytststorageacc": storage.AccountsClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'user@corp.com' with object id '****************************' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write' over scope '/subscriptions/****************************/resourceGroups/my_RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mytststorageacc' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

Sample 2:

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        azurerm = {
            source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
            version = "=3.0.0"
        }
    }
}
provider "azurerm" {  
    features {}
    client_id       = "******************"
    client_secret   = "******************"
    subscription_id = "******************"
    tenant_id       = "******************"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mytststorageacc" {
    name                     = "mytststorageacc"
    resource_group_name      = "my_RG"
    location                 = "centralindia"
    account_tier             = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
```

Error:

```
building account: getting authenticated object ID: listing Service Principals: ServicePrincipalsClient.BaseClient.Get(): clientCredentialsToken: received HTTP status 400 with response: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS700016: Application with identifier '*****************' w`your text`as not found in the directory 'az org'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: ***************************\r\nCorrelation ID: 0000000000000000000000000\r\nTimestamp: 2023-09-13 06:14:59Z","error_codes":[700016],"timestamp":"2023-09-13 06:14:59Z","trace_id":"000000000000000000","correlation_id":"f000000000000000000","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700016"}
```

With the above code I was expecting that it will create a storage account in the resource group for which I have contributor's access.

Instead it is showing errors such as:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215

https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000216

Where as I have thoroughly checked the access and the mentioned details like the client ID, secret ID, tenant ID subscription ID, ideally which should not be required to create a simple storage account.

NOTE: I am able to create the required resources from the Azure portal directly.

Do we need any sort of special permissions for the Terraform code to apply in the Azure? How exactly the Terraform code runs and why is it showing Error 400 and 403, clearly when I have access to the said Resource Group?

Comment: How you login to `Terminal` for authenticating `Azure`. Kindly check which account and subscription is logged in by using **Az account show**, if that user account have Reader on Subscription and Contributor on RG, you can be able to create from Terraform, there is no Specifical permission require to create Storage account from terraform.

Comment: Have you logged in portal with same user user@corp.com? just check in Terminal which account you have logged in? if you are able to create from Portal but not from Terraform might be you logged in with different user.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: creating Azure Storage Account "mytststorageacc": storage.AccountsClient#Create: Failure sending request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'user@corp.com' with object id  does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write' over scope '/subscriptions/****************************/resourceGroups/my_RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/mytststorageacc' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."

The error usually occurs due to insufficient permissions to create a storage account. I also encountered the same error when I tried to create a storage account with the **'Reader'** role in the `subscription`.

[image]

If you are trying to create a `Storage Account` using Terraform, the `Contributor` role is enough. However, in your case, even if you have the `Contributor` role on the `Resource Group`, you may still be unable to create a storage account from `Terraform`. Make sure to check the `subscription` and `Azure AD` user you have logged into the terminal by using the following command

```
az account show
```

You can verify the `Tenant ID` and `Subscription` you are logged into in the Terminal.

[image]

I have the `Contributor` role on the `Resource Group` for that `Azure AD` user.

[image]

```bash
    provider "azurerm" {  
      skip_provider_registration = true
      features {}
    }
    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mytststorageacc" {
      name                     = "mytststorageacc1"
      resource_group_name      = "venkat"
      location                 = "centralindia"
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "LRS"
    }
```

**Terraform Output**

[image]

The storage account was created successfully once I ran the code

[image]

You can also log in to Terraform using a `Service Principal`, such as `Tenant ID`, `Client ID`, and `Subscription ID`, with the required permissions on the `Resource Group`. This method is primarily for automation purposes to avoid manual user authentication.

```bash
provider "azurerm" {  
  features {}
  client_id       = "******************"
  client_secret   = "******************"
  subscription_id = "******************"
  tenant_id       = "******************"
}
```

**For your sample 2 query :** Check if the `Azure AD Application` details being passed exist in the `Azure AD Tenant`. The error usually occurs if the `Application` does not exist in the Tenant